# Is it OK to do a grad school interview if I was already accepted informally by another program?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I recently got accepted to my first choice graduate program, but then my second choice school emailed asking for an interview.

I feel like since I applied, I should at least do the interview, but I am worried that my first choice school will find out and revoke my acceptance. (it was an informal, unofficial acceptance directly from my faculty advisor)

Am I just being crazy? Do professors from different schools talk about their PhD applicants? Should I still do the interview?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me - you don't have a formal acceptance letter, and until then, you aren't actually accepted and it would be reasonable to check out your other options.

Comment: _I am worried that my first choice school will find out and revoke my acceptance_ — Any department that would revoke their offer to admit you for interviewing elsewhere should be avoided at all costs.  (I'm assuming here that you have not yet accepted their admission offer.)

Answer (score 8):

I would advise that, until you have a formal, firm offer letter, you keep following the steps of the rest of applications you submitted. Even after making you an admission offer, you will have some time to consider any other option and decide (many people get accepted in multiple programs and it is fully alright and understood). Now, once you *accept* an offer (not only receive it), it is very recommended that you contact the other programs that have made you an offer, and tell them that you will not be attending there because you already accepted an offer somewhere else. They will all understand, of course. But, most important, if you tell them as soon as you have decided, then they will have some time to make an offer to another candidate.